# Changing django admin header

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm very new to programming and have just started going through the django project tutorial. In part 2 of the tutorial, it shows you how to customize your project template by changing the header of the django admin page. For some reason, after following the instructions to a T, I cannot get it to work. The admin header does not change, remains as "Django Administration". I've looked around for solutions, tried a few, no luck. One solution was to use a relative file path instead of absolute but this did not work either.

Here is my code for the TEMPLATE_DIRS settings on the settings file (mysite/settings):

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Work1/GitProjects/DjangoPolls/mysite/templates',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Here is my code for the base_site.html:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Polls app' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Polls app' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

I have also tried syncdb and running the server again with no changes.

Comment: Where did you put `base_site.html`?

Comment: I put base_site.html in /Work1/GitProjects/DjangoPolls/mysite/templates/admin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution was to put the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting after the TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting. (Just put it in the end :)).